# custom Action Bar like in youtube app

Tags: android, actionbar

Добрый день, я хочу сделать Action Bar в стиле нового приложения Youtube. Т.е. ActionBar в несколько уровней. Строка поиска, ниже всякие там кнопочки, как это можно реализовать?

Comment: А то у меня получается, что отображается только строка поиска, а то, что под ней то ли не влазит, то ли еще что-то, пытался изменять высоту ActionBar' а не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переходите на `Toolbar`, для поиска используйте `SearchView`. Эти два виджета созданы друг для друга и вам не придется пилить велосипед

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот кнопочки, которые называются табами. Для них используйте `TabLayout` + `ViewPager`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S Скриншоты из моего приложения, в котором я изучал все элементы Material Design и виджеты из библиотек

Код на гитхабе:

1. [Toolbar & SearchView](https://github.com/ATumbler/Material-Demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ru/albatros/material/TBRV.java)
2. [ViewPager & TabLayout](https://github.com/ATumbler/Material-Demos/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ru/albatros/material/VPTL.java)

Суть приложения:

Главный экран с 18 пунктами. 18 активностей:

1. `FAB` при клике перемещается на рандомные координаты
2. При клике на `FAB` снизу всплывает `SnackBar`
3. При клике на `FAB` снизу всплывает `BottomSheet`
4. Тупая реализация `FABMenu`
5. При скроллинге `RecyclerView` плавает `FAB` и `Toolbar`
6. `GridView` + `Transitions`
7. Сцены
8. `CircularReveal`
9. `CollapsingToolbarLayout` + `NestedScrollView`
10. Сдвигающаяся `CardView`
11. `TextInputLayout` + `PasswordVisibilityToggle`
12. `SearchView` + `RecyclerView`
13. Добавление в список/массовое удаление из списка
14. Сортировка списка + Удаление свайпом + Drag & Drop
15. `ViewPager` + `TabLayout`
16. `DrawerLayout` + `NavigationView` + `Header/Footer`
17. `BottomNavigationView`
18. `RecyclerView` + `CardView`

Comment: Если нужно могу залить код на гитхаб и дополнить ответ ссылкой

Comment: было бы не плохо

Comment: заранее спасибо

Comment: @Kostya M, дополнил. Не за что!

Comment: ссылки на гит битые

Comment: @Илья Чижанов, да, ответ мой устарел, код удален..